# Make table with filter in react failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm able to make the filter works but simply use the filter of es6, but then the problem is I don't know how to reset the state back to the original source.

Usually the data source is an API calls but it possible to make avoid api call when the user deleted the value from the filter input?

```
const data = [
  {
    Id: "1",
    FirstName: "Luke",
    LastName: "Skywalker"
  },
  {
    Id: "2",
    FirstName: "Darth",
    LastName: "Vader"
  },
  {
    Id: "3",
    FirstName: "Leia",
    LastName: "Organa"
  },
  {
    Id: "4",
    FirstName: "Owen",
    LastName: "Lars"
  }
];


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      data: data
    }
  }

  filterId(e) {
    const Id = e.target.value
    if (Id) {
      this.setState({
        data: this.state.data.filter(v => v.Id === Id),
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        data
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <table>
          <th>Id <input type="number" onChange={e => this.filterId(e)} /></th>
          <th>Name<input /></th>
          {this.state.data.map((o, i) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{o.Id}</td>
                <td>{o.FirstName}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/oo22451v25

Comment: one option is, store the same data twice, (originalData, filteredData) initial value of both will be same and always filter the data from originalData and update in filteredData.

Comment: @MayankShukla true, I think I got it!

Comment: sample example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ko5yk719r, this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You may either store filtered data in separate variable or do data filtering dynamically in `render` function, like `this.state.data.filter(v => v.Id === this.state.Id).map(...)`.

Comment: @JennyMok could you explain please?

Answer (score 0):

There are several thing you could do, but I would advice not to change the original data stored in the state, but rather add a new state property which holds the data when the original data is filtered.

You could then assign this new state object to a variable and output it this way.

It could then look somethiing like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    firstName: 'Luke',
    LastName: 'Skywalker',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    firstName: 'Darth',
    LastName: 'Vader',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    firstName: 'Leia',
    LastName: 'Organa',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    firstName: 'Owen',
    LastName: 'Lars',
  },
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: data,
      filteredData: null,
    };

    this.filterId = this.filterId.bind(this);
  }

  filterId(e) {
    const id = e.target.value;
    if (id) {
      this.setState({
        filteredData: this.state.data.filter(v => v.id === id),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        filteredData: null,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const dataOutput = this.state.filteredData || this.state.data;
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <th>
            id <input type="number" onChange={e => this.filterId(e)} />
          </th>
          <th>
            Name<input />
          </th>
          {dataOutput.map((o, i) => {
            return (
              <tr key={o.id}>
                <td>{o.id}</td>
                <td>{o.firstName}</td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Oh, and one more thing: Use camelCase. Capital letters at the beginning should only be used when declaring classes.

Comment: pls test ur answer before post an invalid non working code.

Comment: Sry, I had the styles variable in my component, but forgot to copy it here. I removed the style and it now works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

First up: You're going to want to filter using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) for usability. Otherwise things won't match until they're 100% identical. This will matter once you start to deal with fields longer than one digit.

Secondly: Filtration via the [`render()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) method will allow you to search more robustly, ie allow you to backspace to unfilter, as `this.state.data` will remain pristine.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Data.
const data = [
  {
    Id: "1",
    FirstName: "Luke",
    LastName: "Skywalker"
  },
  {
    Id: "2",
    FirstName: "Darth",
    LastName: "Vader"
  },
  {
    Id: "3",
    FirstName: "Leia",
    LastName: "Organa"
  },
  {
    Id: "4",
    FirstName: "Owen",
    LastName: "Lars"
  }
]

// Filter.
class Filter extends React.Component {

  // Constructor.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {data, query: ''}
  }

  // Render.
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>

          <tr>
            <input placeholder="Query" type="number" value={this.state.query} onChange={event => this.setState({query: event.target.value})} />
          </tr>

          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>

          {this.state.data.filter((point) => point.Id.includes(this.state.query)).map((o, i) => {
            return (
              <tr>
                <td>{o.Id}</td>
                <td>{o.FirstName}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}

        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Filter/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: You can add or statements `||` to the `filter()` to check for other matches

Comment: If you decide to add more fields